# For Each Reverse Using FileSystemObject

Tags: vba, loops, foreach, filesystemobject

I need to reverse this loop:

I've tried using "Step -1", but has not worked.
I guess it's because that's a FSO method of loop.

```
Set d = fso.GetFolder("address")

For Each File In d.files

    If (Int(Mid(File.Name, 30, 5)) = Int(nfprocurada)) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=File.Path, ExtraInfo:=False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

[For Each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) loops don't accept any change in Step size or sign. So if you want to reverse the direction, you'll need to change looping types to an [index based loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) like `For counter = start to end`. Since a [Files collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/files-property) doesn't accept an index as an arguement, you'll need to copy each file to an array before you are able to loop through the files with an index.

Try this:

```vb
Set d = FSO.getfolder("address")

Dim AllFiles() As Object, FileCount As Integer

For Each File In d.Files
    ReDim Preserve AllFiles(FileCount)
    Set AllFiles(UBound(AllFiles)) = File
    FileCount = FileCount + 1
Next File

Dim i as Long
For i = UBound(AllFiles) To LBound(AllFiles) Step -1
    If (Int(Mid(File.Name, 30, 5)) = Int(nfprocurada)) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=AllFiles(i).Path, ExtraInfo:=False
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i
```